# $urlRouterProvider.otherwise doesn't recognize $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, []) in a function of a controller

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a state in my app.js :

```
.state('app.kamus', {
    url: '/kamus',
    views: {
        'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/kamus.html',
            controller: 'Kamus1Ctrl'
        }
    }
})
...
```

and :

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/kamus');
```

controller :

```
.controller('Kamus1Ctrl', function($scope, $cordovaSQLite, $ionicLoading, $stateParams, $timeout) {

$ionicLoading.show({
    content: 'Loading',
    animation: 'fade-in',
    showBackdrop: true,
    maxWidth: 200,
    showDelay: 0
});

$scope.selectAll = function() {
    $scope.datas = [];
    var query = "SELECT * FROM data";
    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, []).then(function(res) {
        $scope.datas = [];
        if (res.rows.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {

                $scope.datas.push(res.rows.item(i));
            }
        } else {
            console.log("No results found");
        }
    }).finally(function() {
        $ionicLoading.hide();
    });
}
$scope.selectAll();
```

})

I direct the $urlRouterProvider.otherwise to /app/kamus to show kamus page in first launch of my application. But it seems $urlRouterProvider.otherwise is failed to execute $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, []) in my selectAll() function on Kamus1Ctrl.

But when I use other pages as my $urlRouterProvider.otherwise, i.e : $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('app/other'), then I go to /app/kamus via my side menu(button ui-sref="app.kamus"), it just works.

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Which function are you talking about? What do you expect to happen, precisely, and what happens instead, precisely? Post the relevant code and error stack trace, if any.

Comment: Hello, I've just updated my post. I expect that selectAll() function is called by the first time my apps is launched. The error is the ionicloading won't hide because of the selectAll() function is not recognised when I use $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/kamus')

Comment: And how do you diagnose that it is not called? What happens instead?

Comment: This is just my hypothesis, I said it is not called because the IonicLoading won't hide on my page, I think selectAll() function is correct. I try to go to app/kamus page via my side menu(using ui-sref="app.kamus") it just work, the data loaded, and ionicloading is disappeared by .finnaly condition. But I want to open my app/kamus page as the first seen pages when my apps is opened. I use $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('app/kamus'), it won't load my selectAll() function, it just stuck on $IonicLoadingShow.

Comment: Use your debugger. Put a breakpoint in selectAll(). Put one in the callback functions. Check for errors in the console.

Comment: hi, it seems that $cordovaSQLite.execute can't be executed with $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/kamus'). I've try to use alert("") to track the controller either its work or not. The result is it can reach the controller, it can reach selectAll() function, but when it face  $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, []).then(function(res) ,,, it just stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

**Index.html**

```
<body>
    <div>  
    <h3>Index page</h3>
        <div ui-view="main"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**kamus.html**

```
<div ui-view="view1"></div>
```

**Controller**

```
var routerApp = angular.module('routerApp', ['ui.router']);

routerApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('app');

    $stateProvider    

    .state('app', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/app',
        views: {
            'main': {
                 templateUrl: 'kamus.html',
                 controller : 'Kamus1Ctrl'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('app.kamus', {
        url: '',
        views: {
            'view1@app': {
                template: "Im View1"
            }
        }
    });

});

routerApp.controller('Kamus1Ctrl', function($scope, $cordovaSQLite, $ionicLoading, $stateParams, $timeout) {
alert("Inside controller");
    $scope.selectAll = function() {
        alert("Inside selectAll");  
        //rest of the code
    }

    $scope.selectAll();
    })
```

**NOTE:** In ui-router dot operator is used for inner states.

Comment: I have try this to my project with several adjustment, but $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, []) is still can't be accessed. But controller and selectAll() function is working.

Comment: I don't have experience on ionic and cordova, so added cordova tag to the question. I hope you will get help from them.